# How to send value corresponding to the onChange Event in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have my frontend setup in angular 2 for a list of users assigned to certain teams as given below in the picture. The picture has a dropdown i.e OffShore-1 etc of teams that I want to change whenever the user clicks on a certain team in the dropdown. I want to send the patch request to the Backend Django Server with `team_name[newly changed]` and the corresponding `email` of the person. I tried to add the onChange event but it only gives me the instance of changed team as it should. I want to send the email back to the list-user.ts component so that I can send the data for a patch request to take place. I am unable to decipher a solution being very new to the Angular Environment
[image]
Here is component.html file for the same

```html
       <tr class="table-row" *ngFor="let user of listUsers;let indexOfelement=index;">
           <td class="col-md-1 table-cell">{{indexOfelement+1}}</td>
           <td class="col-md-1 table-cell" >{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</td>
           <td class="col-md-1 table-cell" >{{user.email}}</td>
           <!-- <td class="col-md-1 table-cell" >{{user.team.name}}</td> -->
           <span class="form-group pad " id="team" >
            <select (change)="onChange($event)" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" label="caseType" id="caseType">
              <option  [value]="user.team.name" >{{user.team.name}}</option>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let item of listTeam" >

                <option *ngIf="user.team.name!=item.name" [value]="item.name">
                    {{item.name}}
                 </option>
              </ng-container>
              
            </select> 
           </span>
           <td class="col-md-1 table-cell action" ><a class="btn btn-primary" href="">Edit</a>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way by changing `onChange($event)` to `onChange($event,user.team.email)` and was able to get the email and the team_name in the on change event. I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this though

Comment: Yes there is nothing wrong with sending additional parameters in the event handler.